# Condensing Find/Replace Excel script

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to condense my script as i still have a long ways to go and even with copying and pasting this will take me a long time. I am just looking to condense the Find/Replace Functions

```
Function ZoneChanges()

Dim MyCell As range

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set MyCell = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)

MyCell.Replace What:="EE", Replacement:="DA", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
MyCell.Replace What:="EF", Replacement:="DB", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

MyCell.Replace What:="EG", Replacement:="DC", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

MyCell.Replace What:="EH", Replacement:="DD", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Function
```

Thank you!

Comment: Should be migrated to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It would probably be best to implement the changes suggested by JapanDave first before trying Code Review, as there is only so much to say about copy-pasted code other than "loop over a data set instead"

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do multiple find and replace, you could put all the values in arrays and run a loop. The problem is, that this would be slower than what you have now. But, purely to shorten the code you could do this.

```
Function ZoneChanges()

Dim MyCell As Range
Dim arrWhat, arrRep, i As Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set MyCell = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)
arrWhat = Array("EE", "EF", "EG", "EH"): arrRep = Array("DA", "DB", "DC", "DD")
     For i = LBound(arrWhat) To UBound(arrWhat)
        MyCell.Replace What:=arrWhat(i), Replacement:=arrRep(i), LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
     Next

End Function
```